# How to call a static file from a block styling url in django properly

Tags: html, django

I have the following line: `<div class="slide-item" style="background: url('{%static 'images/landing/slide/slide1.jpg'%}');">` .This correctly gets the image I intend but VSCode marks it as an error with the following messages: `at-rule or selector expected` `) expected`. I am not sure how this can be fixed and I already tried double quotes with no success. All my html files are in the templates folder and my css,js and images on the static folder. The page works correctly but the fact that is marked as an error makes me wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Visual Studio can not "understand" Django template language, it sees it as a simple HTML, and for a simple HTML file, this would indeed be a problem. But the Django render engine will substitute the `{% static ... %}` for something else).

Comment: That makes sense you saved me a lot of possible wasted time